# Make text flicker usinf Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Now I want my text to flicker jus like a tube light. This means there should be some noise in its blinking. it should not be a set definite interval in which opacity changes.
Here is what I came up with:

```
//find the text i want to flicker
text = document.getElementById("flicker");
console.log(text);

//initialise with 0
text.style.opacity=0;

//logic of wait function
function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
   }
 }

while(true){

    //logic to invert the opacity
    if(text.style.opacity=1)
        text.style.opacity=0;
    else if (text.style.opacity=0)
        text.style.opacity=1;

    //find a random time interval b/w 0 to 0.5 sec
    randVal = Math.random()*500+1;

    //wait of that time and repeat the process for ever
    wait(randVal);
}
```

Now the problem comes when I load the web page.
 IT DOES NOT LOAD 
MY GUESS: the infinite while loop is the problem and is running even before the DOM loads
but I have added the script at the end of my HTML file

Comment: The loop execution is gonna be too fast to notice the difference to the human eye. Change the while loop to a setInterval with a timedelay of ~ 200 ms and you should be able to see a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a setTimeout and toggle a class instead.

```js
//find the text i want to flicker
const text = document.getElementById("flicker");
console.log(text);

const getDuration = () => {
    //find a random time interval b/w 0 to 0.5 sec
    const randVal = Math.random()*500+1;
    console.log(randVal);
    return randVal;
};

const doFlicker = () => {
    //logic to invert the opacity
    text.classList.toggle('clear');
        
    setTimeout(doFlicker, getDuration());  
};

setTimeout(doFlicker, getDuration());
```

```css
.clear {
  color: #00000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="flicker" class="clear">Flicker</div>
```

Comment: is there any way of doing this in pure CSS

Comment: You should be able to loop an animation in CSS, but you would lose the random element.

Comment: yes exactly that is why I made in on JS but the thing is that this might block other JS running on the page

Comment: Not using the `setTimeout` is won't.